# Making Postback Asynchronous in C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, asynchronous, webforms, postback

So I know how to do this sort of thing in Python for the web, PHP (extremely easy there), and most languages where you write your own code for stuff rather than generating it.

However, I'm being forced to use webforms here, so I've no choice. How would I turn the code below into an asynchronous version where the content under the IsPostBack is called asynchronously via a button click and a gif file (loading.gif) is shown in an image placeholder on the page until finished?

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (IsPostBack)
    {
        videoidmatch = contentcheck();
        video = videoget();
        if (videoidmatch.Success)
        {
            string videoid = videoidmatch.Groups[1].Value;
            videotitle = videotitle + "-" + videoid;
            if (System.IO.File.Exists("/output.gif"))) {
                showstuff(video, videotitle, videoid);
            } else if (System.IO.Directory.Exists("~/gifprocess/")) {
                makegif(videotitle);
                showstuff(video, videotitle, videoid);
            } else if (System.IO.File.Exists("/moviefiles/test.avi")) {
                dumpframes(video, videotitle);
                makegif(videotitle);
                showstuff(video, videotitle, videoid);
            } else {
                downloadmovie(video, videotitle);
                dumpframes(video, videotitle);
                makegif(videotitle);
                showstuff(video, videotitle, videoid);
            }
        }
        else
        {
            TextBox2.Text = "An error has occurred. Go away.";
        }
    }
}
```

Normally I'd just have a page that functions as an API and takes in form data and pipes out a response, then I'd post to that via JavaScript. But I've got zero idea how to do that 'properly' in C# web-form land.

Comment: There's essentially no difference.  HTTP requests are HTTP requests, regardless of the server-side technology.  You'd make the request from JavaScript and need a server-side handler just as anywhere else.  In this case the server-side listener would likely be an ASHX handler: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb398986(v=vs.100).aspx  It could also be an ASPX page if that's easier for you.  It's slightly less performant, but often not a big deal.

Comment: I believe you can use a thread to download the movies

Comment: Any chance of getting a demo of that? I could theoretically attempt to emulate the request itself, but C# webforms post a billion pieces of information beyond the simple named elements and these are mysterious and unknown to me. Also, how would I produce a response with webforms?